# applicationDidBecomeActive with a specific view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, view, subview

I have a project consisting of a window, a main view and many view that are called from the main view with the method "addSubview" and removed "removeFromSuperview", I would make sure that by the method

```
- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive: (UIApplication *) application {
```

my app each time you return from active background charging a specific view named viewTest. I tried with

```
[window addSubview: viewTest];
[window makeKeyAndVisible]
```

but if I send my app in the background with a view different from the viewTest active again when I show, however, the view of the first and not the viewTest.

Someone can help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add viewTest as a subview of the view controller property of window:

```
[window.viewController addSubview:viewTest];
```

If you're using a navigation controller it will be different.